# how can I get the first element of a XElement

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

how can I get the first element

```
<outline title="Javascript" text="Javascript"> </outline>
```

from this XElement

```
<outline title="Javascript" text="Javascript">
 <outline text="j" title="j" type="rss" xmlUrl="http://wwww.Java.com/rss2.xml"/>
</outline>
```

this is my code

```
var desireXElement =existXElement.Where(w => (string) w.Attribute("title") == "Javascript").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what the problem is, if you have the XElement already, why would you need to search for it? The only change from the input I see is that the child "outline" element is removed. Do you want to remove that from the original element? Or do you want to remove the child from a copy? Perhaps doing `XElement desiredElement = new XElement(existXElement.DescendantsAndSelf("outline").First(el => el.Attribute("title").Value == "Javascript")); desiredElement.Nodes().Remove();` ias what you want, it searches for the first "outline" with that title, creates a copy, removes children

Comment: I want to select only first element without its child elements.your code do it.
tanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't select a node without that node containing its child nodes.  Such a "selection" would be equivalent to a mutation.  You can create a new XElement that is a copy and then mutate the new one:-

```
 var desireElement = new XElement(existXElement.Where(w => (string)w.Attribute("title") == "Javascript").First());

 desireElement.RemoveNodes();
```